# How can I compare sitemaps between two sites (staging and production)

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

I have rebuilt a site for a client but want to limit the SEO fallout upon deployment of their new website.

How can I compare sitemaps from both sites in an effort to make sure that the sites are the same, or at least very close

Comment: If you expect the sites to be the same, then copy the data from one server to the next. and even then, you'll likely get in trouble with google if you try to index both sites because google HATES duplicate content and will only choose one of the website copies to index.

Comment: @Mike, it sounds like this is part of a site redesign.   The sites are supposed to have the same pages, but the design or server technology has changed.   The new site is not live yet and he wants to make sure that the newly generated sitemap has the same URLs that the old sitemap had.

Comment: @stephenOstermiller yes this is the reality.  We just want to do an extra step of due diligence to make sure the new site won't tank SEO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Google search led me to this program:

[XML comparison tool](https://www.corefiling.com/opensource/xmldiff.html)

It's free and online, let us know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks for this link.  I had googled before I posted, but hadn't found that.

Answer (score 1):

Download both sitemaps to your desktop, right click on them and select 'open with' then select Excel

Select 'As an XML Table' from the next prompt, then click yes on the next prompt about not all schema being visible.

Copy and paste the two different lists of URLs into a single document in adjacent rows, then use [conditional formatting](http://spreadsheetpro.net/comparing-two-columns-unique-values/) or [formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213367) to find the matching URLs.

Answer (score 0):

For large sitemaps: files containing: ~ 7,000,000+ URLs, you can use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638802/456983) script (doesn't require to install anything).